# ViewPager2 - fragment layout disappears after multiple swipes via tabs

Tags: android, android-viewpager2

I'm using `ViewPager2` which is hosted inside a fragment. On the initial opening of `ViewPager2` fragment host everything is loaded and displayed correctly, but when I swipe multiple times (via `TabLayout`) to the last fragment and go back to the first fragment, its layout is empty/white screen.

The adapter which I'm using is `FragmentStateAdapter`. Also, I set `offscreenPageLimit` to a constant value (which is in most cases less than the size of the fragments list in `ViewPager2`).

This is constructor of my custom `FragmentStateAdapter`:

```
pagerAdapter = MyCustomPagerAdapter(requireContext(), childFragmentManager, viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycle)
```

Since `ViewPager2` is using `RecyclerView` internally, maybe there is some problem with recycling fragments when there are not visible (also considering `offscreenPageLimit` value).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was in [by viewBinding()](https://gist.github.com/Zhuinden/ea3189198938bd16c03db628e084a4fa#file-fragmentviewbindingdelegate-kt) method for getting binding object.

After using [standard way](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding#fragments) of creating binding object everything is working OK.